# How to make WebClient wait until previous download is finished?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, webclient

I'm using `DownloadFileAsyncTask` method to download files. However, when i execute it in a loop i get an exception, which tells me concurrent operations are not supported. I tried to fix it like this:

```
  public async Task<string> Download(string uri, string path)
    {
        if (uri == null) return;

        //manually wait for previous task to complete
        while (Client.IsBusy)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }

        await Client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri(absoluteUri), path);

        return path;
    }
```

Sometimes it works, when a number of iterations isn't big(1-5), and when it runs 10 or more times i'm getting this error.
 `Client` here is a `WebClient` and i create it once. I don't produce a new Clients on every iteration because it makes an overhead.
Back to i was saying, how to make `WebClient` wait before previous download finishes? Also a question here is why `IsBusy` works for small amount of downloads.
The code i'm using:

```
 public IEnumerable<Task<string>> GetPathById(IEnumerable<Photo> photos)
    {
        return photos?.Select(
                     async photo =>
                     {
                         var path = await Download(Uri, Path);
                         return path;
                     });
    }
```

I want to download many files and don't block my Ui thread. Maybe there is other way to do this?

Comment: Why are you performing lots of downloads at the same time in the first place if you're only ever going to make each of them wait until no others are working before they actually do their work?  If you want to only download one at a time, then don't start more than one at a time; only star the next one when the previous one finishes.

Comment: . I don't produce a new Clients on every iteration because it makes an overhead. -> Is it really an overhead?

Comment: @Zbigniew Well it's the difference between executing the various downloads in parallel vs sequentially.  That would dramatically increase the density of the network load.  Whether you would actually want to (or be able to) perform the operations in parallel will of course depend on the situation.

Comment: Yes, the reason i don't create a new instance is that is goes slower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a lot of code that is necessary to help you out so I wrote this quick example to show you what I'm thinking you might want to try. Its in .NET Core but its essentially the same, just swap HttpClient for WebClient.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var toDownload = new string[] { "http://google.com", "http://microsoft.com", "http://apple.com" };
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var downloadedItems = await DownloadItems(client, toDownload);

        Console.WriteLine("This is async");

        foreach (var item in downloadedItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }).Wait();
}

static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> DownloadItems(HttpClient client, string[] uris)
{
    // This sets up each page to be downloaded using the same HttpClient.
    var items = new List<string>(); 
    foreach (var uri in uris)
    {
        var item = await Download(client, uri);
        items.Add(item);
    }
    return items;
}

static async Task<string> Download(HttpClient client, string uri)
{
    // This download the page and returns the content.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri)) return null;

    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    return content;
}
```

Comment: You should very, very rarely ever be using `ContinueWith`.  You should almost always be using `await` outside of very rare situations where you *Really* know what you're doing.